Android Studio Koala: Devices Don't Pair Over Wifi
Curious if anyone else has dealt with this and found a solution.
The Issue:
Pairing my Pixel 7 via wifi does not work in Android Studio Koala (2024.1.1), and I've tried on both MacOS and Debian. The loading spinner just spins forever, and never seems to time out.
Both MacOs and Debian versions of Android Studio did connect the very first time. After that, it seems borked forever.
The Sanity Check:
I can consistently connect over wifi using adb directly from the command line. This is cumbersome, though, and I shouldn't have to do it!
The Versions:
Android Studio: 2024.1.1 (Build #AI-241.15989.150.2411.11948838, built on June 10, 2024)
adb: 1.0.41 (35.0.1-11580240)
Thoughts, advice, snide comments?

Did you see similar answers available here?

I have faced this situation with almost every version of android studio, maybe everyone faced it once in a while.
Whenever this happens, I go to wireless debugging screen and forget the paired devices and then on next try device gets connected normally.

Thank you for the reply! Unfortunately, I have tried this several times to no avail.
